# Instant Search not working on IMAP folders Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook, imap, windows-search

I have 3 IMAP accounts and two POP accounts set up in Outlook 2013. Instant Search works perfectly on the POP accounts and Search works on all accounts but in the IMAP mailboxes when I type something in the Instant Search box the results pane goes blank except for "Searching ..."

If I change the dropdown on the right to "All Mailboxes" I get results from the IMAP folders. Of course I get results from all the other mailboxes too which makes the search results a bit crowded.

I have tried rebuilding the Windows index a number of time, it doesn't help.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: In Control Panel > Indexing Options, Microsoft Outlook should be appearing as a blue Outlook 2013 icon. Are the IMAP accounts being cached locally? Meaning, are the e-mail header and body being fully downloaded? If so, then the Windows Search should be indexing them.

Comment: Noticed the same as the OP (and thank you for providing a workaround which also works for me!).  This used to work fine and I believe it was broken by a recent M$ patch, eg: Update for Microsoft Outlook 2013 (KB2986204) 64-Bit Edition

Answer (score 8):

Actually ... you do not need to uninstall the update.

Just change the search from "Current Mailbox," to "Current Folder," and you are all set.

If you set the default search settings to include results only from "Current Folder," not "Current Folder. Current Mailbox when searching from the inbox," (which seems to be the default) all of your IMAP folders will be "searchable" again.

Comment: does not seem to work for me, nor do I have KB2986204 installed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  It happened with Microsoft's last round of updates and is constrained to IMAP folders.

Uninstalling "Update for Microsoft Outlook 2013 (KB2986204)" will solve this issue.  (Open Installed Updates by going into Control Panel, Programs, and then, under Programs and Features, clicking View installed updates.)